# Use case of shared_from_this and this

Tags: c++, boost-asio, smart-pointers

In [this source file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime7/src.html) there are two classes : `tcp_connection` and `tcp_server`. I've seleceted the relevant bits of code in my opinion but you might want to refer to the full source code for more information.

```
class tcp_connection : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_connection>
{
public:
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<tcp_connection> pointer;

  void start()
  {
    message_ = make_daytime_string();

    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message_),
        boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this()));
  }
};

class tcp_server
{    
private:
  void start_accept()
  {
    tcp_connection::pointer new_connection =
      tcp_connection::create(acceptor_.get_io_service());

    acceptor_.async_accept(new_connection->socket(),
        boost::bind(&tcp_server::handle_accept, this, new_connection,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }
};
```

My question is simple : what would we use `shared_from_this` as a `bind`argument within the `async_write` function and use `this` as a `bind`argument within the 
`async_accept`function?

Comment: Can reference counter of `tcp_connection` be 0 without `shared_from_this()` ? Similar question for `tcp_server`. I would say yes and no.

Comment: does the `tcp_server` get created in a `shared_ptr`? `shared_from_this()` is UB (or throws post C++17) if it isn't.

Comment: What is a UB? @Caleth

Comment: @Caleth be that as it may, it answers the wrong question (the question is not why can't you use `shared_from_this`, the question should be why it isn't being used/needed)

Comment: @PierreP. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shared pointers govern the lifetime of a dynamically allocated object. Each held pointer increases a *reference count* and when all held pointers are gone the referred to object is freed.

### The Server

There's only one server, and it's not dynamically allocated. Instead, the instance lives longer than the acceptor (and possibly the io_service) so no all async operations can trust the object to stay alive long enough.

### The Connections

Each client spawns a new connection, dynamically allocating (make_shared) a `tcp_connection` instance, and then starting asynchronous operations on it.

The server does **not** keep a copy of the shared-pointer, so when all async operations on the connection complete (e.g. because the connection was dropped) the `tcp_connection` object will be freed.

However because the object must **not** be destroyed when an async operation is in progress, you need to bind the completion handler to the shared pointer (`shared_from_this`) instead of `this`.

Comment: Took me a few reading to really get your answer, but now it's much more clear! Thanks

Comment: Such a clear answer. I leaned from you as well. Thanks :)